# Question relating to components in SMPS

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

Why is the ESR (Equivalent Series Resistance) of the electrolytic capacitors important?

Comment: Sometimes it's irrelevant. Sometimes it's quite important. Sometimes it's vital.

Answer (score 0):

Electrolytic capacitors are used to smooth the voltage rippleson the input and output of a smps. Due to this, a ripple current is imposed on the capacitor. This current causes heat rise due to losses caused by the ESR. Therefore, for a given ripple current, a lower ESR value will cause less loss.

Electrolytic capacitors have a liquid electrolyte. Heat causes this to boil off. Less electrolyte causes a rise of ESR. This is the basic failure mechanism. Sometimes the heat rise causes the electrolyte to boil causing the capacitor to swell and/or vent. At this point the capacitor has failed.

Comment: On top of Kartman's comment, the ESR \$r_C\$ of the output capacitor combined with the capacitance \$C_{out}\$ introduces a zero \$\omega_z\$ located at \$\frac{1}{r_CC_{out}}\$. If this zero occurs before cross-over it offers phase boost but as ESR moves up and down in relationship with temperature, lifetime and production spread, its effect on the control-to-output transfer function must be carefully monitored.

Answer (score 0):

ESR is a compromise between low output impedance and preventing oscillations.

At frequencies between a few 100 Hz and 10s of kHz the ESR of the output bulk capacitors is often the deciding factor for power supply impedance..So lower is better in this regard.

However in SMPS you also form an LC output filter which can oscillate with too low series resistance. A little bit of ESR helps to damp oscillations in the kHz range. Even lower frequency oscillations can be damped by the voltage feedback of the PSU itself.